# Saving pandas dataframe containing vertical tabs

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've got a program that saves data from database to Excel table. It worked well so far, but it turned out to have problem with texts including vertical space (hexa 0B ASCII). How can I make the program more robust? Is there an easy way to add some parameters to the `pd.ExcelWriter` or to the `df.to_excel` that solves the problem?

This is the example code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x", "y\vz"], b=[1, 2]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x\vxx", "yz"], b=[11, 22]))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
for sheet_name, df in (("first", df1), ("second", df2)):
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
writer.close()
```

The Excel file has several worksheets and many columns, many of them are text. I know that I could do something like this:

```py
for sheet_name, df in (("first", df1), ("second", df2)):
    df["a"] = df.a.apply(lambda x: x.replace("\v", "\n"))
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

or even doing this on each string column, but is there any simpler solution?

(Python 3.11, pandas 1.5.3, openpyxl 3.1.2)

Comment: The problem is related to the problems serialising these characters in XML. The best solution would probably be to do the substitution as part of the query from the database, or use a view.

Comment: I try to understand. So the Worksheets are stored as XML 1.0 files. And that can't store special characters like vertical tab or line feed. XML 1.1 can store those characters but is not used. The strange thing that if I save the data to CSV, import to Excel, and export to CSV again, than the vertical tab is there.

Answer (score 0):

So far my simplest solution is this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x", "y\vz"], b=[1, 2]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x\vxx", None], b=[11, 22]))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
for sheet_name, df in (("first", df1), ("second", df2)):
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns:    # Here are the changes
        df[col] = df[col].apply(
            lambda x: x.replace("\v", "\n") if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
writer.close()
```

As there can be None values in an object column, I need to check the type in the lambda function. The code that way works even with these data frames.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x", "y\vz"], b=[1, 2]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=["x\vxx", None], b=[11, 22]))
```

Or I can extract a function to do that:

```py
def to_excel_with_replacement(df, *args, **kwargs):
    """Before saves to Excel, replaces the vertical tabs in all the text columns. By default with new line."""
    vtab_replacement = kwargs.pop("vtab_replacement") if "vtab_replacement" in kwargs else "\n"
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace("\v", vtab_replacement) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    df.to_excel(*args, **kwargs)


for sheet_name, df in (("first", df1), ("second", df2)):
    to_excel_with_replacement(df, writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```